R: stat_density2d change color of density surface?
I'm using this example to create a heatmap in R:
https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-crime-heatmap-in-r/
ggmap(map_sf) +
  stat_density2d(data = sf_crime, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = ..density..), geom = 'tile', contour = F, alpha = .5)

How would I change the color of the density surface?  It defaults to blue; what if I want red for example?
If I do:
ggmap(map_sf) +
  stat_density2d(data = sf_crime, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = ..density..), geom = 'tile', contour = F, alpha = .5, color="red")

It simply overlays a red grid on the map.

Use fill instead. In ggplot2, color is for the lines, fill for the areas.

Besides the issue with using color instead of fill, the main issue is that the fill colors are determined by the scale_fill_xxx.
In case of a continuous variable mapped on fill the default fill scale (used under the hood) is scale_fill_gradient which defaults to a gradient running from a light to a dark blue.
If you want a red gradient instead you have to set your desired colors by explicitly calling scale_fill_gradient.
Using a minimal reproducible example based on the default example from ?stat_density_2d:
library(ggplot2)

m <- ggplot(faithful, aes(x = eruptions, y = waiting)) +
  stat_density_2d(
    aes(fill = after_stat(density)),
    geom = "tile", contour = FALSE
  )

m



m +
  scale_fill_gradient(
    low = "darkred", high = "red"
  )


